# Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1

Tags: r

I just want to recover the table to the original structure. However, it has an error and I don't know how to debug it.

```
rm(list=ls())
Mytable<-function(mytable){
    rows<-dim(mytable)[1]
    cols<-dim(mytable)[2]
    datatable<-NULL
    for(i in 1:rows){
        for(j in 1:mytable$N[i])
        {
            rowdata=mytable[i,c(1:2)]
            datatable=cbind(datatable,rowdata)
        }
    }
    row.names(datatable)<-c(1:dim(datatable)[1])
    return(datatable)
}
sex<-rep(c('M','F'),each=4)
grade<-rep(c('B','C','D','E'),2)
number<-c(2,11,12,5,2,13,10,3)
table<-data.frame(S=sex,G=grade,N=number,stringsAsFactors=F)
mydata<-Mytable(table)
```

Comment: Where are you using `j`?

Comment: in order to repeat the value of number. For example, the data of first row is M B 2, so I want to have a new table to record the M B for two times.

Comment: Do you want to add another row  with value `M, B, 2` since value is 2? is it?

Comment: What value of `number` you want in new rows?

Comment: Yes. I have found my problem. Thanks.

Comment: I want to have a sequence, just like 1,2,3,……

Comment: There can be better and fast way to do that. Instead of `loop`.

Comment: Can you show the code to me?

Comment: I have added an answer. May be that's what you wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are doing with your function (a more descriptive name will help), but I guess you should use rbind instead of cbind, as it seems that you are binding rows, not columns.

Comment: Yes，I also find my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know where I was wrong now by misusing the cbind to rbind. The correct code is following.

```
rm(list=ls())
Mytable<-function(mytable){
rows<-dim(mytable)[1]
cols<-dim(mytable)[2]
datatable<-NULL
for(i in 1:rows){
    for(j in 1:mytable$N[i])
    {
        rowdata=mytable[i,c(1:2)]
        datatable=cbind(datatable,rowdata)
    }
}
row.names(datatable)<-c(1:dim(datatable)[1])
return(datatable)
}
sex<-rep(c('M','F'),each=4)
grade<-rep(c('B','C','D','E'),2)
number<-c(2,11,12,5,2,13,10,3)
table<-data.frame(S=sex,G=grade,N=number,stringsAsFactors=F)
mydata<-Mytable(table)
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution can be achieved using `tidyr::complete` and `dplyr` to repeat rows number of times mentioned in column `N`. The solution will be as:

```
    library(dplyr)
    library(tidyr)

    table %>% group_by(S,G) %>%
      complete(S,G,N = seq(N)) %>%
      as.data.frame()

# S G  N
# 1  F B  1
# 2  F B  2
# 3  F C  1
# 4  F C  2
# 5  F C  3
# 6  F C  4
# 7  F C  5
# 8  F C  6
# 9  F C  7
#
#.....49 more rows
```

Data

```
sex<-rep(c('M','F'),each=4)
grade<-rep(c('B','C','D','E'),2)
number<-c(2,11,12,5,2,13,10,3)
table<-data.frame(S=sex,G=grade,N=number,stringsAsFactors=F)
```